# multiple access to database qt sqlite3

Tags: qt, sqlite

disclaimer: I'm sorry if the code is not neatly indented.  know some may be irked at this.
I'm using qt5

I have two .cpp(register_user.cpp and parking.cpp) files that will connect to a database. I tried to connect register_user.cpp to the database and it works perfectly fine. It is connected and the sql commands work fine. Tut, I need to also connect another file which is the parking.cpp to the database. I connected parking.cpp to the database and then checked for the connection. it said that it is connected but the sql commands don't work.

How can I connect the second file to the database correctly?

login.h

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <main_interface.h>


namespace Ui {
class Login;
}

class Login : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
QSqlDatabase mydb;

void connClose()
{
    mydb.close();
    mydb.removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
}

bool connOpen()
{
    mydb=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    mydb.setDatabaseName("C:/SQLite/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3250200/IPark.db");

    if(!mydb.open())
    {
        qDebug()<<("Failed to open database");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<("Connected. . .");
        return true;
    }
}

public:
explicit Login(QWidget *parent = 0);
~Login();

private slots:
void on_pushButton_clicked();

void on_pushButton_2_clicked();



private:
Ui::Login *ui;
};

#endif // LOGIN_H
```

register_user.h

```
#ifndef REGISTER_USER_H
#define REGISTER_USER_H
#include <QDialog>
#include "login.h"

namespace Ui {
class register_user;
}

class register_user : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
Login conn;
explicit register_user(QWidget *parent = 0);
~register_user();

private slots:
void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
Ui::register_user *ui;
};

#endif // REGISTER_USER_H
```

register_user.cpp

```
#include <login.h>
#include "login.h"
#include "register_user.h"
#include "ui_register_user.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

register_user::register_user(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::register_user)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

        if(!conn.connOpen())
             ui->label_reg->setText("Failed to open database");
         else
             ui->label_reg->setText("Connected. . .");


}

register_user::~register_user()
{
delete ui;
}

void register_user::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
Login conn;
QString username, plate_number, name;
username=ui->lineEdit_Username->text();
plate_number=ui->lineEdit_Plate_Number->text();
name=ui->lineEdit_Name->text();


  QSqlQuery qry;
  qry.prepare("insert into User(User_id, plate_number, name, spot_number, credit, order_id) values('"+username+"','"+plate_number+"','"+name+"',NULL, NULL, NULL)");

 if(qry.exec()){
     QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("SAVE"), tr("SAVED"));
 }

 conn.connClose();
}
```

parking.h

```
#ifndef PARKING_H
#define PARKING_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "login.h"


namespace Ui {
class parking;
}

class parking : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
Login conn;
explicit parking(QWidget *parent = 0);
~parking();

private slots:

void on_ParkSpace100_clicked();

void on_ParkSpace101_clicked();

void on_ParkSpace102_clicked();

void on_ParkSpace103_clicked();

private:
Ui::parking *ui;
};

#endif // PARKING_H
```

parking.cpp

```
#include <login.h>
#include "login.h"
#include "parking.h"
#include "ui_parking.h"
#include "reservation.h"
#include <QMessageBox>



int status = 0;

parking::parking(QWidget *parent):
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::parking)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
Login conn;

if(!conn.connOpen())
     ui->label->setText("Failed to open database");
 else
     ui->label->setText("Connected. . .");

}

parking::~parking()
{
delete ui;
}



void parking::on_ParkSpace100_clicked()
{

Login conn;




QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("insert into User(User_id, plate_number, name, spot_number, credit, order_id) values('105,0123,'Amethyst',NULL, NULL, NULL)");

if(qry.exec()){
   QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("SAVE"), tr("SAVED"));
}

}

void parking::on_ParkSpace101_clicked()
{
Login conn;

QSqlQuery qry;
conn.connOpen();



qry.prepare("select name from User where spot_number = 101");
bool value = qry.exec();
if(value == true)//true : then someone is on the spot
{
    conn.connClose();
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "Error", "Someone's already in the spot");
    qDebug("Inside ParkSpace101");
}

hide();
Reservation b;
b.setModal(true);
b.setWindowTitle("Reservation Page");
b.exec();

}

void parking::on_ParkSpace102_clicked()
{
QMessageBox::warning(this,"WARNING", "Someone's already in the spot.");
}

void parking::on_ParkSpace103_clicked()
{
Login conn;

QSqlQuery qry;
conn.connOpen();



qry.prepare("select name from User where spot_number = 101");
bool value = qry.exec();
if(value == true)//true : then someone is on the spot
{
    conn.connClose();
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "Error", "Someone's already in the spot");
    qDebug("Inside ParkSpace101");
}

hide();
Reservation b;
b.setModal(true);
b.setWindowTitle("Reservation Page");
b.exec();

}
```

Comment: If you have two databases you have to specify which database your query is for. If you don't, than the query always relates to the default database. Maybe that's the reason why your parking queries do not work?

Comment: I only have one database. both register user and parking are accessing the same database

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to pass a unique `connectionName` into the second argument in `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase()` in the `connOpen` method of `login.h`. This will allow you to add a new database connection while keeping the old one runnning.

Thus the line with `addDatabase()` should resemble

```
mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", your_connection_name_here);
```

---

Make sure that the `connectionName` is different for `register_user` and `parking`. My suggestion is to pass the `connectionName` as a parameter into the constructor of `Login`. Then store this into a member variable.

```
explicit Login(const QString &connectionName, QWidget *parent = 0);
```

And modify the QSqlDatabase functions to handle the member variable

```
mydb.removeDatabase(m_connectionName);
...
mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", m_connectionName);
```

When you initiate Login in `register_user` and `parking`, you can pass in your own connection name.

```
Login conn("register_user_sqlite_connection");
```

If you dislike passing arguments into the constructor, an alternative is to have a setter function for the connectionName.

```
void setConnectionName(const QString &connectionName);
```

then call it right after you initiate Login in `register_user` and `parking`.

```
Login conn;
conn.setConnectionName("register_user_sqlite_connection");
```

---

Further Reading: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase

---

Edit:

#### Minimal Example of Why OP's Code Does Not Work

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>

class Login
{
public:
    QSqlDatabase mDatabase;      // Bad practice: don't use as class member.
                                 // Read more: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#details
    
    Login() {}
    
    bool connOpen()
    {
        // Only the default connection is used.
        mDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
        mDatabase.setDatabaseName("stackOverflow.db");
        
        if(!mDatabase.open())
        {
            qDebug() << ("Failed to open database");
            return false;
        }
        
        qDebug() << "Connected. . .";
        return true;
    }
    
    QSqlQuery exec(const QString& query)
    {
        return mDatabase.exec(query);
    }
};

class RegisterUser
{
public:
    Login conn;
    
    RegisterUser()
    {
        qDebug() << "Opening database from RegisterUser()";
        bool ok = conn.connOpen();
        
        if (ok) qDebug() << "Connection success!";
        else    qDebug() << "Connection error...";
    }
};

class Parking
{
public:
    Login conn;
    
    Parking()
    {
        qDebug() << "Opening database from Parking()";
        bool ok = conn.connOpen();
        
        if (ok) qDebug() << "Connection success!";
        else    qDebug() << "Connection error...";
    }
};


int main()
{
    // Initialise with default connection. 
    RegisterUser reg;
    //  Opening database from RegisterUser()
    //  Connected. . .
    //  Connection success!
    
    qDebug() << reg.conn.exec("SELECT 1").executedQuery();
    //  "SELECT 1"
    
    // STEALS the default connection!!! 
    Parking par;
    //  Opening database from Parking()
    //  QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
    //  QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
    //  Connected. . .
    //  Connection success!
    
    // Query from RegisterUser failed because it's not connected!!! 
    qDebug() << reg.conn.exec("SELECT 1").executedQuery();
    //  QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
    //  ""
    
    qDebug() << par.conn.exec("SELECT 1").executedQuery();
    //  "SELECT 1"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response @John Law, but what i'm most confused about is that the connection of register_user to the database works perfectly fine but the parking connection doesn't. i used the same code to connect register_user and parking

Comment: [Here's a hastebin](https://hastebin.com/okofisipar.cpp) showing a minimal example of what you're trying to accomplish and why it's not working. Since you're using `"the same code to connect register_user and parking"`, they will have the same connectionName. As such, both instances of register_user and parking can't connect at the same time, only one of them will end up being connected. If you want to have two separate connections, then use _two distinct connection names_ (as I have suggested above). Hope this sheds some light upon your predicament.

Comment: I've moved the code from the hastebin to my answer.